Only the last .to_excel is working when trying to update date in excel
df[df['Location'] == 'place1'].to_excel(updated_excel, sheet_name='place1', index=False)
df[df['Location'] == 'place2'].to_excel(updated_excel, sheet_name='place2', index=False)
df[df['Location'] == 'place3'].to_excel(updated_excel, sheet_name='place3', index=False)
df[df['Location'] == 'place4'].to_excel(updated_excel, sheet_name='place4', index=False)

When I open the Excel file, it only contain one sheet - 'place4' - with its data.
I have tried everything, even used "with" but same only last one is working

Did you check that df[df['Location'] == 'place4'] output contains data and not an empty dataframe?

What is updated_excel? A file name?

If this is not an issue of an empty dataframe as suggested in my comment above, try:
with pd.ExcelWriter(updated_excel, mode = 'w') as writer:
    df[df['Location'] == 'place1'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='place1', index=False)
    df[df['Location'] == 'place2'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='place2', index=False)
    df[df['Location'] == 'place3'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='place3', index=False)
    df[df['Location'] == 'place4'].to_excel(writer, sheet_name='place4', index=False)

